# space after figure

Tags: spacing, floats

I am trying to remove the space after the figure until the next line. I do not use a caption. But with \setlength I experienced some problems. How do I might to it the best way? If i remove the  `\\` after the first picture, The text that follows is moving before the picture and it's also nnot an option to use  `\begin{figure}[h]` because the picture is floating.

The purpose of this is to do a cheat sheet. So everythingneeds to be at the right place with as little space between pictures and text as possible.

```
% page setup
\documentclass[]{article}
\pagestyle{headings}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% geometry
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\geometry{headsep=\baselineskip}

% headers and footers
\usepackage{fancyheadings}

% graphics
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{subfigure} 
\usepackage{xypic}
\usepackage{float}

% colums / paragraphs
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{parskip} 
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------

\newgeometry{top=0.55in,bottom=0.55in,right=0.3in,left=0.3in} 
\begin{paracol}{4}

\begin{figure}[H]
\fbox{
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{typI.jpg}}
\end{figure}\\
$\bullet$ Typ II: Insulinresistenz (\underline{polygen})
 \vspace{-0.35cm}
\begin{figure}[H]
\fbox{
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{typII.jpg}}
\end{figure}


 
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You did not provide the figure nor the final result.  Which space are you talking about? From the image to the caption? Or from the caption to the main text below?

Comment: you need to remove the `\\ ` after the first figure, that will be forcing spurious space, also `\centering` inside `\fbox` does nothing so it is not clear what you want for the second figure. Note that if you ise `[H]` you will get large spaces at page breaks by design.

Comment: @João Lourenço: I dont use a caption for the pictures but the space between the end of the \fbox until the next line. I tried to add the two pictures.

Comment: Since you're not interested in a `\caption`, don't use the `figure` environment. Just use `\begin{center} \fbox{\includegraphics[.]{..}} <empty line> \fbox{\includegraphics[.]{..}} \end{center}`. Or, even `{\centering \fbox{...} <empty line> \fbox{...}\par}`.

Comment: Thank you! This helps me a lot! :D

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.